# How to use Microsoft authentication via Firebase in Unity

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, msal

I am trying to use Firebase in Unity(after unsuccessfully trying to get MSAL for Android working within Unity for B2C. Currently, Firebase lets me do a regular email + password register and log in. But when I try to use the Microsoft sign-in feature the app just flashes for a second, my debugger gets detached, and then nothing happens. Any ideas what could be going wrong?

```
    public void SignInWithMicrosoft()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SignInWithMicrosoftAsync());
    }

    private IEnumerator SignInWithMicrosoftAsync()
    {
        var signInTask = auth.SignInWithProviderAsync(provider);

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => signInTask.IsCompleted);
        
        if (signInTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithProviderAsync encountered an error: " +
                           signInTask.Exception);
        }
        else
        {
            AuthResult authResult = signInTask.Result;
            FirebaseUser user = authResult.User;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                user.DisplayName, user.UserId);
        }
    }
```

Tried stripping the provider data down to the bare minimum, and checked to make sure provider contents were valid. I expect it to open a browser(as it states on the Firebase docs) with the Microsoft sign-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it(but also went back to Azure B2C)
For those that might be looking into this kind of thing in the future here's the Firebase issue I had and also how to do stuff with B2C in Android:

Firebase:
My issue was I had to add the SHA-1 and SHA-256 to the firebase console, and also I had forgotten to enable microsoft sign in in the console(so I was just being silly). After that it was opening but I got an error after logging in, didn't go any further than that sorry

Azure B2C:
This one was a bit more convoluted. Things you'd have to do:

- enable customsettings template to pass in the repository(this is in settingsTemplate)

  ```
       maven { 
       url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MicrosoftDeviceSDK/DuoSDK-Public/_packaging/Duo-SDK-Feed/maven/v1' 
   }4
  ```
- enable custom main template to pass in the dependencies needed

  ```
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:4.9.+'
    **DEPS**}
  ```
- enable custom android manifest(this breaks patch and run for me currently

  ```
   <activity android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Add in your scheme/host from registered redirect URI -->
            <data android:scheme="msauth"
                  android:host="com.companyName.appName"
                  android:path="this is the SHA or smth from keystore="/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  ```

you'll then have to do a bunch of JNI stuff to interface with it(its a bit annoying, but it'll look something like this in the end:

```
public class MSALAndroid
    {
        public AndroidJavaObject publicClientApplication;
    
        public string accessToken;
        public TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs;
    
        public MSALAndroid(string clientId, string authority, string redirectUri)
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
            using (AndroidJavaObject applicationContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext"))
            using (AndroidJavaClass publicClientApplicationClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication"))
            {
                publicClientApplicationClass.CallStatic("create",
                    applicationContext,
                    clientId,
                    authority,
                    redirectUri,
                    new MSALApplicationCreatedListener(this));
            }
        }
    
        public Task<string> AcquireToken(string[] scopes)
        {
            tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            try
            {
                using (AndroidJavaObject scopeArray = new AndroidJavaObject("java.util.ArrayList"))
                {
                    foreach (string scope in scopes)
                    {
                        scopeArray.Call<bool>("add", scope);
                    }
                    using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
                    using (AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                    {
                    
                        object[] parameters = new object[3];
                        parameters[0] = currentActivity;
                        parameters[1] = scopes;
                        parameters[2] = new MSALCallback(this);
                        publicClientApplication.Call("acquireToken", parameters);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
    
            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
    
    public class MSALCallback : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        private MSALAndroid msalAndroid;
        public MSALCallback(MSALAndroid msalAndroid) : base("com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthenticationCallback")
        {
            this.msalAndroid = msalAndroid;
        }
        
        public void onSuccess(AndroidJavaObject authenticationResult)
        {
            // Handle successful authentication.
            // You can call authenticationResult.Call<string>("getAccessToken") to get the access token.
            msalAndroid.accessToken = authenticationResult.Call<string>("getAccessToken");
            Debug.Log("ACCESS TOKEN: " + msalAndroid.accessToken);
            
            msalAndroid.tcs.SetResult(msalAndroid.accessToken);
        }
    
        public void onError(AndroidJavaObject msalException)
        {
            var exception = msalException.Call<string>("getMessage");
            Debug.Log(exception);
            // Handle error.
        }
    
        public void onCancel()
        {
            // Handle cancellation.
        }
    }
    
    public class MSALApplicationCreatedListener : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        private MSALAndroid msalAndroid;
    
        public MSALApplicationCreatedListener(MSALAndroid msalAndroid) : base("com.microsoft.identity.client.IPublicClientApplication$ApplicationCreatedListener")
        {
            this.msalAndroid = msalAndroid; 
        }
    
        public void onCreated(AndroidJavaObject application)
        {
            // Handle successful creation here.
            msalAndroid.publicClientApplication = application;
            Debug.Log("Application created!");
        }
    
        public void onError(AndroidJavaObject exception)
        {
            // Handle error here.
        }
    }
```

this code hasn't been tidied up and probably can be improved, but just wanted it out there since I suffered way too much for it